# Error when trying to access Shared files from iMac via smb

Tags: windows-xp, mac, ip-address, smb

I used to access all my Windows XP shared files on my Mac using Finder --> Window --> Connect to server.

Now all of a sudden, an error crops up when I try to connect. I get this error:
`There was a problem connecting to the server "192.168.1.*" The server may not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the server name or IP address, check your internet connection and then try again.`

How can I remove this error and access my shared files from my Mac?

P.S my network connections is fine.

Comment: Are you able to test mounting the share from another computer on your network?

Comment: No. I do not have another system, so I did not try it.
But I think the problem lies in my Windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! I figured out what the problem was.

`File and printing Sharing` was not added to Windows Firewall Exceptions. 
After adding, it works.